# Dropdown box - onchange and onselect

Tags: javascript, html

I want help, i am very new to html..

On selecting option from dropdown menu, I want html to put the values in word..
e.g. When I select "1" from drop down, it must show "one"
When I select "2' from drop down, it must show "two"

How to do that??

```
<HTML>
<Table border=10>

<TR>
<TD>Select Number</TD>
<TD><Select>
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
</Select></TD>
</TR>

<tr>
<td>In Words</td>
<td><input type="text" readonly></td>
</tr>

</Table>
</HTML>
```

Please make a script and show me...

Comment: Please be more clear what your question is.

Comment: I have given example.. do refer to it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**A non-jQuery solution**:

Firstly, give your select- and input-tags id's, and your options values (value=""). Then add a onchange=""-listener in the select-tag and make a function that carries out what you want to do (i.e. checking the selected value and displaying it in your input field), like so:

```js
function showValue() {
    var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
    document.getElementById("mySelection").value = "You selected: " + x;
}
```

```html
<Table border=10>
<tr>
    <td>Select Number</td>
    <td><Select onchange="showValue()" id="mySelect">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    </Select></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>In Words</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="mySelection"></td>
</tr>

</Table>
```

Comment: Upvoted as the question states that the asker is new to HTML and IMHO it makes more sense to learn and understand Javascript first rather than jumping straight into jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand what you want, you'll need some javascript to find what you selected, and take that 'string' and shove it in an element for the user to see.

Here is a working example. Try making one these next time you ask a question. Welcome to Stack Overflow.

http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/6vp5Lskn/

### HTML

```
<select name='my_select' id='my_select'>

    <option value='1'>Option 1</option>
    <option value='2'>Option 2</option>
    <option value='3'>Option 3</option>
    <option value='4'>Option 4</option>
    <option value='5'>Option 5</option>

</select>

<div id="outcome">
    You have selected: <span></span>
</div>
```

### javascript (jQuery)

```
var selectedOption; // define this variable

// when the select is changed...
$('#my_select').on('change', function() {
    // get the option that was selected
    selectedOption = $( "#my_select option:selected" ).text();
    // put the option in the place you want it
    $('#outcome span').html(selectedOption);
});
```

Comment: please, review my edited question.. and wil be thankful if u provide me with working example of query i have given, as i dont know java script... your answer was realy appreciable .. thnx :-)

Comment: I've updated the jsFiddle with some more comments, other than that - I'm not sure what you need on top of what is provided / besides loading jquery... for that, you put `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>` in the <head> of your document.